# How to download file from sharepoint using office365-rest-python-api

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, office365

I was trying to use that lib to connect with my SharePoint and download the file: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

I tried two approaches for auth:

1. UserCredential
2. ClientCredential

Code:

```
client_credentials = ClientCredential(f'{client_id}',f'{client_secret}')
ctx = ClientContext(url).with_credentials(client_credentials)


web = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path("Shared Documents/Documents").expand(["Files", "Folders"]).get().execute_query()

#web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

I registered the app in Azure Portal with a tutorial from GitLab site but in the first example I have an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot get binary security token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
```

in client creds I have:

```
Forbidden 403 Error
```

I have already checked many possibilities:

- whether the user given is correct - email not login
- whether the password is correct - if I enter the wrong one there will be another error
- whether the SharePoint page is correct - if I enter a non-existent one, I get another error
- whether the query produced by the application is ok - if I type it directly in the browser while logged into SharePoint it returns the correct result.

How did I register the applications in Azure?

- I went into AD Azure, created a new application
- I generated a secret for it
- I added to API Permissions read access to SharePoint.

Is there anything else I should do? Did I leave something out? Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem?

I've run out of ideas - all links in google are already in purple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an Azure AD Application with Application Rights on SharePoint, you must use Certificate authentication. ([Official Documentation stating it is typically better to use a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#setting-up-an-azure-ad-app-for-app-only-access)) I could not find the page stating you **must** use a certificate, but that's still something I have experienced countless times.

I read in your question

> I added to API Expose read access to SharePoint.

Which should rather be: *I added to API Permissions a SharePoint Application right of Sites.Read.All* if I understood correctly

You then have two options:

1 - Use a certificate

2 - Give rights to your application on SharePoint using the SharePoint Add-In Method (deprecated but works and used everyday)

For method 2, you will find hidden pages in SharePoint Sites. The one you're first interested in is `<sp-site>/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` where you can enter your AAD App ID and click "Search", which will auto-complete the App name. You may then complete the App Domain & Redirect URL with the given examples ([www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com) & https://www.contoso.com/default.aspx) as they are not important in your use case. The XML may be filled according to your needs, and you will find an [interesting documentation here](https://medium.com/ng-sp/sharepoint-add-in-permission-xml-cheat-sheet-64b87d8d7600). For example, to have Read rights on the whole web, it would be this exact XML (no replacing the URLs):

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Please note you must be this SharePoint site Administrator (and not only in the Owners group) to grant such a right.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer and explanation. I will try this solution. Of course you are right, I added API Permissions - corrected.

Comment: Thanks for tip @Gostron. I ask the administrator to add that policy to my app, and I still got that error but with different error values. Instead:  `(None, None, "403 Client Error: Forbidden for URL: my_url)` I have `-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.', '403 Client Error: Forbidden for URL:`. 

What can be a problem? Could it be because the admin has not added App Domain and Redirect URL?

Comment: Just a client ID, client Secret, and adding rights on `appinv.aspx` should be sufficient. App Domain and Redirect URL are a non factor in your use case. There should be something you missed somewhere. You can manually check your token and requests using postman or `curl` if you want. To do so, you must POST a form url-encoded with client_id, client_secret, grant_type='client_credentials' and resource='00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/$targetHost@$tenantId' where $targetHost is <tenant>.sharepoint.com and $tenantId can be retrieved on https://www.whatismytenantid.com.

Comment: This post must be made to "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/$tenantId/tokens/OAuth/2" and will give you and access token you can use on future requests. Then, make a GET to `<sp-site>/_api/web` with header Authorization: `Bearer <access_token>`. This should necessarily work if your steps were correct

Comment: Thanks, @Gostron. On SharePoint I have three websites (sites?). And I noticed if I list the Web title, I just got the name of one of these websites. I targeting another website. So maybe instead of `http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection` should I ask for `http://sharepoint/content/tenant` ?

Comment: If you want tenant-wide access (meaning to all site collections), the `appinv.aspx` must be done from the SharePoint Central Administration site collection (so `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`) with the correct XML. However if your needs just require you to access a few pre-determined site collections, you should rather do the procedure on each. Please note that authentication must be made independently on each site collection as a token is scoped to a SharePoint Site Collection.